# Very confused about domain names

Tags: discussion, subdomains

A little while ago, there was a pulse of noise here about the question of domain names: *.stackechange.net versus something.clever.com.

My recollection is that the endstate of that discussion was that the management had plonked for *.stackexchange.net.

Now I see askubuntu.com and some others. Was there a further flip of the flop?

Comment: Also http://answers.onstartups.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/

This is covered in

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/ubuntu-stack-exchange-is-askubuntu-com/

1. this partnership predates that decision
2. I’d argue that the possibility of a redirect from ask.ubuntu.com (tbd, but under discussion) invokes the “act of God” provision in our naming rules. That’d be like apple.com endorsing our apple site.